# Meteor form textbox dont clear after submit

Tags: javascript, forms, mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am running Meteor 1.4 and i try to cler the textbox with the submit button i already red every blog post about this problem but nothing is fixing it

Here is my HTML

```
<template name="NeuesEvent">
     <head>
    <title>Event_Planner</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    {{> NavBar}}

        <form class="add-event" >
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Event Name" />
            <input type="submit" value="Bestätigen" />
        </form>

  </body>
</template>
```

and this is the js

```
Template.NeuesEvent.events({
    "submit .add-event": function(event){
        var name = event.target.name.value;

        Events.insert({
            name: name,
            createdAt: new Date()
        });

        event.target.text.value = "";

        return false;
    }
});
```

everything is in the right folder and works fine only the clear function doesnt work help is really appreciated Thanks ;)

Comment: `event.target.name.text.value = "";` ? I added .name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could possibly just be a typo:

**Try this code:**

```
Template.NeuesEvent.events({
    "submit .add-event": function(event){
        var name = event.target.name.value;

        Events.insert({
            name: name,
            createdAt: new Date()
        });

        event.target.name.value = "";

        return false;
    }
});
```

Changed the line `event.target.text.value = "";` to `event.target.name.value = "";`

Comment: Thank you this was it + a restart from the meteor server thank you very much

Comment: No worries, happens to the best of us, just check this answer as the answer, and you'll be good to go.

Comment: LOL - Good'ol StackOverflow.  My apologies.  Good luck on the rest of your project!

Comment: maybe you can help me with this problem too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41986310/meteor-passing-an-id-into-a-link

Comment: lol, I missed it by about a minute.  You're in pretty good hands here - the Meteor community is actually a very good one.  Also, sometimes you have a question which isn't StackOverflow appropriate (requires more discussion, or you're looking for opinions) - in this case, check out forums.meteor.com - The water is warm and everything is nice there.

Comment: here i could need help ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42010811/meteor-creating-a-scrollable-div