# Meteor passing an id into a link

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

now my database is working i want the user to click on one of the things in the database to get a more detailed view but the id of the data is not inserted in the link

```
<template name="meineEvents">
  <ul>
    {{#each event}}
      <li>{{name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    <a href="/eventDetails/{{_id}}">mehr  Details</a>
  </ul>
</template>
```

but when i click on the link i only see the `http://localhost:3000/eventDetails/` without the id behind the eventDetails/ im running Meteor 1.4 with Blaze

Thank you for your help ;)

Answer (score 4):

You need to have the anchor inside the `{{#each}}`

```
<template name="meineEvents">
  <ul>
    {{#each event}}
      <li>{{name}}
      <a href="/eventDetails/{{_id}}">mehr  Details</a></li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>
```

Comment: Floyd beat me to the punch ;) . (this is why he has 11.9k and I have only 900 rep)