# Meteor creating a scrollable div

Tags: javascript, html, css, meteor, meteor-blaze

Hey guys new day new question ;)  im trying to make a scrollable div should be no problem but it does not work ;( in the div i am outputting names of my database and when the space is too small you should scroll it but the scrollbar doesnt appear

my html:

```
<template name="friendsScroll">
  <div class="CSSFreundeScrollListe">
    <ul>
      {{#each friend}}
        <li>{{Name}}</li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

my css

```
.CSSFreundeScrollListe{
background: #00BFFF;
height: 150px;
overflow: scroll; (or auto both "should" work;))
width: 200px;
border: 1px solid #000;
padding: 10px;
}
```

javascript is working fine thats what i get[image]

hope you can help me thanks ;)

Comment: Your CSS is correct. Can you use your browser's inspector to verify that the correct CSS is actually being loaded/applied to that element? Your browser may be loading old, cached CSS

Comment: in the inspector i can see nothing about this css but the blue background and the rest is working fine so i think the css is applied

Comment: Just to make sure that new styles are loading correctly: if you change the background color in your CSS file to red, does element change color?

Comment: i dont know what happened but i changed the color to red and the scroll bar appeared thank you it helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ninja Pixel helped me to find the problem in the comment section and the problem was that the css was not updating then i changed the background color in the css and it got updated and the scrollbars appeared too  thanks again ninjaPixel ;)